# Crossjoin using QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, cross-join

How could I replace the HQL query below using QueryOver API?

```cs
var sql = "from Role r, Action a where r.Active = :active and a.Active = :active";
var result = manager.Session.GetISession().CreateQuery(sql)
            .SetBoolean("active", true).List();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't *believe* there's a way to do this in QueryOver, since both `JoinAlias` and `JoinQueryOver` require an expression describing a path to the related entity.

However, this is easy to accomplish in LINQ-to-NHibernate:

```
var result = 
    (from role in manager.Session.GetISession().Query<Role>()
    from action in manager.Session.GetISession().Query<Action>()
    where role.Active == true && action.Active == true).ToList();
```

With NH 3.2, here's the SQL I get:

```
select role0_.Id    as col_0_0_,
       action1_.Id as col_1_0_
from   [Role] role0_,
       [Action] action1_
where  role0_.IsActive = 1 /* @p0 */
       and action1_.IsActive = 1 /* @p1 */
```

Comment: Though the solution above avoids magic-strings issue of projections but I dont belive it is the good one. This is because the above statement will lead the NHibernate to querry the database many times. Let's say Role table has 4 records, Action table has 6 records. The first query NHibernate executes is to return 4 records from Role table. Then for each returned record, NHibernate will read the database to get 6 records from Action table. In other word, the number of routes to the database are equal to the number of returned records from the first query and adding to one.

Comment: Andrew, I tried and the result is what I described above. Could you do the same?

Comment: @tilonthuduc: I posted the SQL I get--Could it be the NH version?